# cant' run IOIOFactory.create()

Tags: android, ioio

first of all, I have no problems running all the examples in APP-IOIO0504.zip.

Because my App has timing concern (in terms of mini sec), I would like to create an IOIO connection myself instead of using `BaseIOIOLooper` (i.e. another thread) or `IOIOActivity`

---

When I run the code "`IOIOFactory.create()`", it shows up this error:

> 10-14 22:02:59.473: E/IOIOFactory(29160): No connection is available.
>   This shouldn't happen.

---

My environment:

> Android: 4.4.2,
>
> IOIO hardware: spark0020
>
> Firmware: App-IOIO0500
>
> Bootloader: IOIO0400

ps, I post on Google group IOIO-users, but got no response. Please show me a direction,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code (copied from one of the Android-specific classes) solved this problem for me:

```
IOIOConnectionRegistry.addBootstraps(new String[] {
    "ioio.lib.impl.SocketIOIOConnectionBootstrap",
    "ioio.lib.android.bluetooth.BluetoothIOIOConnectionBootstrap",
    "ioio.lib.android.accessory.AccessoryConnectionBootstrap",
    "ioio.lib.android.device.DeviceConnectionBootstrap"});
```

It should be more straight-forward to use the basic IOIO classes. The Android-specific helpers are much too "frameworky" for my taste / use case.